# Increase indexPath programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

How can I increase a `var` of type indexPath programmatically? For Example, the current indexPath is [0, 44] and I want that after a specific action the indexPath is [0,45]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working with a collection view you appear to want to increment the `item` property.

```
someIndexPath.item += 1
```

You can also create a new `IndexPath` based on the old one if needed:

```
let newIndexPath = IndexPath(item: oldIndexPath.item + 1, section: oldIndexPath.section)
```

Comment: Check that you didn't exceed the number of rows in that section `let rowsInSection = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: oldIndexPath.section); let newRow = min(rowsInSection - 1, oldIndexPath.row + 1); let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: newRow, section: oldIndexPath.section)`

Comment: @Carpsen90 I left any kind of validation as an exercise for the OP since no details have been provided in the question.